# log4j2 configuration builder instead of xml file

Tags: log4j2

I have followed the instructions here almost exactly -

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html

in the part under "Initialize Log4j Using ConfigurationBuilder with a Custom ConfigurationFactory

it says on this page that

```
The below example overrides the getConfiguration() method to return a 
Configuration created by the ConfigurationBuilder. This will cause the 
Configuration to automatically be hooked into Log4j when the LoggerContext 
is created. In the example below, because it specifies a supported type of 
"*" it will override any configuration files provided.
```

but I am not quite sure what this means...
I can't get it to use my custom configuration factory built configuration instead of the log4j2.xml one. I have tried making that file empty or deleting it and I get a "No Logging Configuration found" error.

I have tried initializing my custom configuration factory, and setting the loggercontext with Configurator.initialize with that configuration, as well as setting a configuration file to that configuration then initializing log4j2 after that but it still wont work...

```
    customConfigurationFactory factory = new customConfigurationFactory(true, true, 5, 2, true);
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    loggerContext = Configurator.initialize(factory.getConfiguration(loggerContext, ConfigurationSource.NULL_SOURCE)); 
    Configuration config;
    config = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
```

and it still won't accept the configuration factory configuration, even though i am initializing the logger after the code above

it is building the configuration when I call that code above, as i see the messages building it in the console, however,  even though it is building the configuration log4j2 is not using it as I am getting this error -

```
[Fatal Error] log4j2.xml:1:1: Premature end of file.
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing
```

(I left a blank xml file when i get this error and if I remove xml file completely I get there is no configuration error)

I am told it has to be recognized as a plug in and this custom configuration factory class can be used in place of an xml file, so i added this declaration at the top -

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
@Order(50)
```

does anyone have any idea on how you initialize log4j2 with this custom configuration factory plugin class like you are supposedly supposed to be able to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using log4j2 configuration builder to initialize logger after startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553699/using-log4j2-configuration-builder-to-initialize-logger-after-startup)